# How to uncheck "My billing and shipping address are the same" checkbox during checkout? One Page/Magento2

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, magento2.2, onepage-checkout, billing-address

I am having an issue where the box is being marked automatically. I want to unmark it.

[image]

Comment: Do you want to unchecked check-box and all input filed should visible all time ? Or it should take shipping value already filled ?

Answer (score 1):

Copy the following file to your theme:

> vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/js/model/checkout-data-resolver.js

and comment out the lines like below:

```
applyBillingAddress: function () {
    var shippingAddress;

    if (quote.billingAddress()) {
        selectBillingAddress(quote.billingAddress());

        return;
    }
    shippingAddress = quote.shippingAddress();

    // This comment is for uncheck the billing address on payment page
    /*if (shippingAddress &&
        shippingAddress.canUseForBilling() &&
        (shippingAddress.isDefaultShipping() || !quote.isVirtual())
    ) {
        selectBillingAddress(quote.shippingAddress());
    }*/
}
```

And also copy the following file to your theme:

> vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/js/model/shipping-save-processor/default.js

and comment out the lines like below:

```
saveShippingInformation: function () {
    var payload;

    // This comment is for uncheck the billing address on payment page
    /*if (!quote.billingAddress()) {
        selectBillingAddressAction(quote.shippingAddress());
    }*/

    payload = {
        addressInformation: {
            'shipping_address': quote.shippingAddress(),
            'billing_address': quote.billingAddress(),
            'shipping_method_code': quote.shippingMethod()['method_code'],
            'shipping_carrier_code': quote.shippingMethod()['carrier_code']
        }
    };

    payloadExtender(payload);

    fullScreenLoader.startLoader();

    return storage.post(
        resourceUrlManager.getUrlForSetShippingInformation(quote),
        JSON.stringify(payload)
    ).done(
        function (response) {
            quote.setTotals(response.totals);
            paymentService.setPaymentMethods(methodConverter(response['payment_methods']));
            fullScreenLoader.stopLoader();
        }
    ).fail(
        function (response) {
            errorProcessor.process(response);
            fullScreenLoader.stopLoader();
        }
    );
}
```

Don't forget to run static-content:deploy and cache flush.

Comment: That did not work. @sukumargorai

Comment: The checkbox was still marked

Comment: Flush the cache. Delete the pub/static/front-end and then run static content deploy. It should work.

Comment: Do I have to delete the static/front-end? @sukumargorai

Comment: Yes may be updated file is not generating. If not then try to update the same on vendor and check it in private browser.

Comment: This is in the vendor directory. What other vendor file should I edit? @sukumargorai

Comment: No I have told you in answer to copy the following file to your theme. If you edited directly in vendor then its ok. Delete the pub/static/frontend and run the static content deploy then check in private browser

Comment: Ok so it worked but the billing address form does not show. All it did was uncheck the box. See my question I have updated it. @sukumargorai

Comment: I ll update the answer tomm.

Comment: I am not near to my system. Let's continue tomm

Comment: @DevAnd I have updated my answer. Revert the changes I have asked you yesterday. Use the updated answer it should work.

Comment: Ok so it's working but still asking the user to update the address. Anyway it doesn't ask user to update? Please look at my original question I have placed a screenshot. Thanks for all this help. @sukumargorai

Comment: Any idea? @sukumargorai

Comment: There is a update button.

Comment: Yeah any idea how to remove that update button and not make the user click that button? @sukumargorai

Comment: You can find that button on details.html file. I ll update the location.

Comment: If you goto this path vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/billing-address.html. You will find the Update and Cancel button there. You can copy that file to your theme and update it accordingly.

Comment: I would like for checkout to accept the address entered into the billing address form. @sukumargorai

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/80229/discussion-between-sukumar-gorai-and-devand).

Comment: Hi were you able to solve issue? @sukumargorai

Comment: Sorry, Not resolved yet.

Comment: Hi. the billing form is disapearing when a user has auto fill form data. Any ideas on how to stop that? @sukumargorai

Comment: Hi? @sukumargorai Need help. This is not working good it's very buggy. Do you know how I can display both the shipping and billing address forms?

Comment: @DevAnd Are you using the default theme and default checkout?

Comment: @SukumarGorai, this will uncheck the checkbox always, can we just uncheck only if we have enabled the store pick up, is like that can be achieved?