# How to un-check "billing address same as shipping address" and keep billing address form open by default?

Tags: magento2, checkout

By default I want to keep "My billing and shipping address are same" button un-checked and billing address form open on checkout page. For this I have copied billing-address.js file in my theme at `app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/Magento_Checkout/web/js/view/billing-address.js` and inside `quote.billingAddress.subscribe` I have added my code as given below

```
if (quote.isVirtual()) {
   this.isAddressSameAsShipping(false);
} 
/* my custom code starts*/
if(window.checkoutConfig.quoteData.delivery_type == 'store') {
    this.isAddressSameAsShipping(false);
    jQuery( ".action-edit-address" ).trigger( "click" );
}
/* my custom code ends*/
```

After adding above code, checkbox is un-checked but still form is not open. If I paster trigger code in browser's console form is getting opened ? How I can make the form also open?

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/233374/how-to-uncheck-my-billing-and-shipping-address-are-the-same-checkbox-during-ch/233377#233377

Comment: Refer This
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/160020/magento-2-uncheck-my-billing-and-shipping-address-are-the-same-checkbox-in-che