# Uncheck billing and shipping address are same checkbox in magento2 if pickup store is enabled

Tags: magento2, checkout, shipping-methods, billing-address

I have installed a store pick up module.

So, I am trying to uncheck the checkbox of "My billing and shipping address are same" once the module is enabled.

I have refered the below link, this will uncheck the checkbox always regardless of which shipping method selected.

[How to uncheck "My billing and shipping address are the same" checkbox during checkout? One Page/Magento2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/233374/how-to-uncheck-my-billing-and-shipping-address-are-the-same-checkbox-during-ch)

Can we uncheck only when store pick up is selected as **"Yes"** or when the particular shipping method is selected during the checkout?

Can this be achieved? Please anyone look into this and update me your Answers.

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've added the modification logic to the original code. Please check:

Copy the following file to your theme:

> vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/js/model/checkout-data-resolver.js

```
applyBillingAddress: function () {
    var shippingAddress;

    if (quote.billingAddress()) {
        selectBillingAddress(quote.billingAddress());

        return;
    }
    shippingAddress = quote.shippingAddress();

    if (shippingAddress &&
        shippingAddress.canUseForBilling() &&
        (shippingAddress.isDefaultShipping() || !quote.isVirtual())
    ) {
        if(quote.shippingMethod()['method_code']=='store pick_up code'){
           //uncheck here
        }else{
           //check here
           selectBillingAddress(quote.shippingAddress());
        }
    }
}
```

And also copy the following file to your theme:

> vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/js/model/shipping-save-processor/default.js

```
saveShippingInformation: function () {
    var payload;

    if (!quote.billingAddress()) {
        if(quote.shippingMethod()['method_code']=='store pick_up code'){
           //uncheck here
        }else{
           //check here
           selectBillingAddress(quote.shippingAddress());
        }
    }

    payload = {
        addressInformation: {
            'shipping_address': quote.shippingAddress(),
            'billing_address': quote.billingAddress(),
            'shipping_method_code': quote.shippingMethod()['method_code'],
            'shipping_carrier_code': quote.shippingMethod()['carrier_code']
        }
    };

    payloadExtender(payload);

    fullScreenLoader.startLoader();

    return storage.post(
        resourceUrlManager.getUrlForSetShippingInformation(quote),
        JSON.stringify(payload)
    ).done(
        function (response) {
            quote.setTotals(response.totals);
            paymentService.setPaymentMethods(methodConverter(response['payment_methods']));
            fullScreenLoader.stopLoader();
        }
    ).fail(
        function (response) {
            errorProcessor.process(response);
            fullScreenLoader.stopLoader();
        }
    );
}
```

Don't forget to run static-content:deploy and cache flush.

Comment: @magefrms, i am getting this error in console,default.js:44 Uncaught ReferenceError: selectBillingAddress is not defined

Comment: thanks i am able to resolve by changing this line to selectBillingAddressAction(quote.shippingAddress()); from selectBillingAddress(quote.shippingAddress()); in default.js

Comment: that's great. sorry I was busy did not able to check your comment

Comment: sure let me checj

Comment: @jafarpinjar but I can't seem to understand why it happened. can you send me your custom module and let me check from my machine

Comment: No, @magefms, that module has some more functionality, just create on controller with my code and on click call that controller by passing product id,

Comment: okay can you give me controller code, the one posted seems to be has something wrong

Comment: hi, @fnsthird, I have updated my code, pls let me know where do you feel its wrong,

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/310890/magento-2-how-to-display-my-billing-and-shipping-are-same-based-on-customer-grou @fmsthird Can you answer this question please ?